# How access Apache Virtual Host with a mobile device? https port 443

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I would like Use your phone's camera to scan. qrcode via web application(localhost) so i want to use https. But I don't understand how to write the address.I have tried https://192.168.1.152/www.ABC.local but not available through my phone

Comment: PHP is being hosted on the phone?  `https://localhost/`?

Comment: PHP is being hosted on the phone? correct  https://localhost/? correct  http://192.168.1.152/ABC can be used normally

Comment: http://192.168.1.152/ABC can be used normally ,PC = https://www.ABC.local can be used normally , phone = https://www.ABC.local not available

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to open my web camera using library jsqr via my phone inside localhost.

Comment: I did some research on the internet telling me to use https to enable my camera, so I asked for an ssl from https://ssl.indexnl.com/ and when I got https, I didn't know what to write in the address. How does the phone point to my server? I don't know if it can be done or not. (But in the server can turn on the camera normally)

Comment: I want to use the web to scan QRcode in my factory where I need to share multiple phones via internal WIFI.

Comment: If I can't, I'll have to study writing Android and iPhone apps, but I don't know if I can do it or not.